# Git Authentication Failed

Tags: git, bitbucket, github-desktop

After committing changes using the Github Desktop app, I tried doing a sync and received the following error message "You may not have permission to access . Check Preferences to make sure you’re still logged in."

I'm using a MacOS running Sierra and my repo is in bitbucket. Also, I'm able to use the git commands (push, pull, checkout etc) via the terminal to manipulate my repo. I would love to continue using my GitHub Desktop so if there is anyone out there who can assist me in resolving the "Auth Failed" error I would be most appreciative.

Comment: what is the sync do? and can you do it via terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still logged in? If yes, then try logging out-and-in again. Some times, theirs just login instance issues.